# What language(s) is the best for do automatically things?

Tags: windows

with which programming language **i can do things like**:

- Click on a program or open it
- Click on a position (x, y) on the screen
- Open a chrome tab
- Click the screen n times
- Close chrome in n minutes
- Turn off the PC in n minutes
- Execute cmd commands
- Placing a song on youtube in a browser
- File installer

in short, actions of that kind, what language does that do? It occurs to me that c ++ or python, but I still do not have it clear, or also the multipurpose languages, but which is the most suitable for this?

Comment: was changed the title, thanks melpomene

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be an opinionated question but my answer would be Python. Use Selenium webdriver for automating web browser, image based recognition if it's stable enough, or you use win32 lib to execute backend to name a few. Each language offers similar such as Java but my preference is python. Happy hunting.